# Determine frequency of duplicate values from two Hashmaps

Tags: java, hashmap

I have created 2 HashMaps that store string values from two txt files. I am able to successfully print which values are duplicated amongst both Maps, however, I am having trouble determining how many times each values are duplicated.

Here is my code to identify duplicate values:

```
 // find if hashmaps contain duplicate values
    boolean val = wordsMap.keySet().containsAll(wordsMap1.keySet());

// create new entry for hashmap
for (Entry<String, Integer> str : wordsMap.entrySet()) {
System.out.println("================= " + str.getKey());


if(wordsMap1.containsKey(str.getKey())){
    System.out.println("Map2 Contains Map 1 Key");
   }


}

System.out.println("================= " + val);
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

I am thinking of something along the lines of

```
Map.values().equals(Map1.values()){
 count++;

}
```

Comment: The only way I can think of is to create one map between duplicate key and the count of its duplicate values, increment counter whenever a duplicate is found

Comment: you want the number of keys that are in both maps, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find values which are common to two map objects. (Add `null` and/or other checks as required)

```
public static int duplicateCount(Map<String, Integer> m1, Map<String, Integer> m2) {

    int count = 0;
    Collection<Integer> m1Values = m1.values();
    Collection<Integer> m2Values = m2.values();

    for (Integer i : m1Values) {
        if (m2Values.contains(i)) {
            count++;
        }

    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of duplicate keys between Maps,

```
public static int getDuplicateKeyCount(Map<?, ?> m1, Map<?, ?> m2) {
    Set<?> tempSet = new HashSet<>(m1.keySet());
    tempSet.retainAll(new ArrayList<>(m2.keySet()));
    return tempSet.size(); 
}
```

To get the number of duplicate values between Maps,

```
public static int getDuplicateValueCount(Map<?, ?> m1, Map<?, ?> m2) {
    List<?> tempList = new ArrayList<>(m1.values());
    tempList.retainAll(m2.values());
    return tempList.size();     
}
```

To get a Map containing the frequency of the values of m1 in m2

```
public static <K, V> Map<V, Integer> getValueFrequencyMap(Map<K, V> m1, Map<K, V> m2) {
    Map<V, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();

    Collection<V> col = m2.values();

    for(V val : m1.values()) {
        freq.put(val, Collections.frequency(col, val));
    }

    return freq;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample program have written based on my understanding of your doubt. It finds and displays the duplicate keys and also the duplicate values along with their frequencies of repetition. The logic is: To find the frequency, pass the duplicate element from *map1* and the *map2* as a parameter to *countFrequency()* method, which in turn will return the count of repetition.

```
package com.rahul.stackoverflow;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class DuplicateValHashMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        map1.put("A", 1);
        map1.put("B", 2);
        map1.put("C", 3);
        map1.put("D", 4);
        map1.put("E", 5);

        map2.put("A", 1);
        map2.put("F", 2);
        map2.put("G", 1);
        map2.put("H", 3);
        map2.put("B", 2);

        for(Entry<String, Integer> entrySet : map1.entrySet()){
            if(map2.containsKey(entrySet.getKey())){
                System.out.println("Map2 contains keys of map1.");
                System.out.println("Duplicate keys are : " + entrySet.getKey());
            }
            if(map2.containsValue(entrySet.getValue())){
                System.out.println("Map2 contains values of map1.");
                System.out.println("Duplicate values are : " + entrySet.getValue()+  
                        " which is repeated " + countFrequency(map2, entrySet.getValue())+ " times.");
            }
        }

    }

    public static int countFrequency(Map<String, Integer> map, Integer value){
        int count = 0;
        for(Entry<String, Integer> entrySet : map.entrySet()){
            if(value == entrySet.getValue()){
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;

    }

}
```